# Unfolding a billiard trajectory on an unbounded billiard table

Tags: dynamical-systems, billiards

A common "trick" used in the study of polygonal billiards is to *unfold* the trajectory.

I'm interested in billiards which may be bounded in one direction, and unbounded in another. For instance, consider billiards in a square with two opposite edges identified. Aside from the particles departing at an angle equal to $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ (or $0, \pi$ depending on which sides are identified), all trajectories will eventually reach one of the identified sides. Does it make any sense to unfold the trajectory in situations like this?

Doing some sketches on paper, this seems perfectly possible (up until the trajectory reaches an identified edge). But I don't know what it means to tile the plane with these objects. For comparison, if we unfold billiards in a square, we end up with a trajectory on the flat torus $\mathbb{T}^2$.

Comment: I think trajectories will be geodesics on the cylinder - does that sound right?

Comment: Yes I believe that is correct. I am confused about the conditions under which we view the system in this way, and when we decide to tile the plane instead. For instance tiling the plane with squares is equivalent to identifying all edges which gives us geodesics on torus. However working on the plane with squares is surely easier than on the torus, so I guess that is why we might do that.. I was wondering if there is an analogous perspective for viewing unbounded billiards.

Comment: I think you just tile the plane with strips.

Comment: Any thoughts, Joppy?

Comment: Sure, I agree. This is what I presumed from "doing some sketches". Though it's not hard to consider unbounded billiards on domains other than a rectangle and arrive at unfoldings which don't make much sense.

Comment: Does this sound right? unfolding "works" $\iff$ the billiard table is the fundamental domain (+ its boundary) of some quotient of $\mathbb{R^2}$

Comment: Maybe that's what makes billiards hard, Joppy, and why there are still unsolved problems in the area.

Comment: @user25959 Is this restrictive enough do you think? What about a flattened cone with incision chosen such that the resulting "wedge" does not go evenly into the original domain?